# Override <b> within class using scss?

Tags: sass

`<b>` normally means bold.

I want `<b>` to mean `font-weight:600`, but only within the class `new-design`. It should also apply in nested classes within new-design.

Is this possible to do with scss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS

```
.new-design {
    b {
       font-weight: 600;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.new-design b {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```